# Fastest way to insert 30 thousand rows in a temp table on SQL Server with C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, bulkinsert, sqlbulkcopy

I am trying to find out how I can improve my insert performance in a temporary table in SQL Server using c#. Some people are saying that I should use SQLBulkCopy however I must be doing something wrong as it seems to work much slower than simply building an SQL insert string instead.

My code to create table using SQLBulkCopy is below:

```
public void MakeTable(string tableName, List<string> ids, SqlConnection connection)
    {

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE ##" + tableName + " (ID int)", connection);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        DataTable localTempTable = new DataTable(tableName);

        DataColumn id = new DataColumn();
        id.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
        id.ColumnName = "ID";
        localTempTable.Columns.Add(id);

        foreach (var item in ids)
        {
             DataRow row = localTempTable.NewRow();
             row[0] = item;
             localTempTable.Rows.Add(row);
             localTempTable.AcceptChanges();
        }


        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
        {
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "##" + tableName;
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(localTempTable);

        }
    }
```

This way my inserts take a long time to run. I got my inserts to work faster in another way:

I created the inserts bit as a string and joined it in my SQL create temp table statement:

Creation of inserts string:

```
public string prepareInserts(string tableName, List<string> ids)
    {
        List<string> inserts = new List<string>();

        var total = ids.Select(p => p).Count();
        var size = 1000;

        var insert = 1;

        var skip = size * (insert - 1);

        var canPage = skip < total;

        while (canPage)
        {
            inserts.Add(" insert into ##" + tableName + @" (ID) values " + String.Join(",", ids.Select(p => string.Format("({0})", p))
                        .Skip(skip)
                        .Take(size)
                        .ToArray()));
            insert++;
            skip = size * (insert - 1);
            canPage = skip < total;
        }

        string joinedInserts = String.Join("\r\n", inserts.ToArray());

        return joinedInserts;

    }
```

Using them in the SQL statement after creating query:

```
inserts = prepareInserts(tableName, ids);

var query = @"IF EXISTS
                                            (
                                            SELECT *
                                            FROM tempdb.dbo.sysobjects
                                            WHERE ID = OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..##" + tableName + @"')
                                            )
                                                BEGIN
                                                    DELETE FROM ##" + tableName + @"
                                                END
                                            ELSE
                                                BEGIN
                                                    CREATE TABLE ##" + tableName + @"
                                                    (ID int)
                                                END " + inserts;

            var command = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection);
...
```

Since I've seen people telling me (on stack exchange https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44217/fastest-way-to-insert-30-thousand-rows-in-sql-server/44222?noredirect=1#comment78137_44222 ) That I should use SQLBulkCopy and that would be faster I believe that I should improve the way I do it. So if anyone can suggest how I can improve my SQLBulkCopy code OR tell me if there is a better insert statement that can improve  my application's performance that would be great.

Comment: Where does the data for this list of strings come from in the first place?

Comment: It will be a set of keys that will come from another application. I haven't done this link yet. For now it's an array that I created with some ids for test.

Comment: 30,000 id's probably come from a database somewhere.  If so, I'd be looking for a way to do all this with sql.

Comment: It probably won't come from SQL, that's why the need to create a temporary table for my case.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your problem may be in `localTempTable.AcceptChanges();` Since it commit your changes.
If you do the next , I think it will run faster

```
    foreach (var item in ids)
    {
         DataRow row = localTempTable.NewRow();
         row[0] = item;
         localTempTable.Rows.Add(row);

    }

    localTempTable.AcceptChanges();

    using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
    {
        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "##" + tableName;
        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(localTempTable);

    }
```

From [MSDN - DataSet.AcceptChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.acceptchanges.aspx)

> Commits all the changes made to this DataSet since it was loaded or
>   since the last time AcceptChanges was called.

Comment: It did run faster. Thanks!

Comment: For some metrics - I implemented this code for a process that inserted 400,000 records and it takes about 3-4 seconds to finish (3.866 according to SQL Server Profiler), which was about half the time of a previous implementation (using an indexed temp table)

Answer (score 6):

I run this code myself with StopWatch objects to measure time.  It’s the AcceptChanges in every iteration that makes go slow.

```
public void MakeTable(string tableName, List<string> ids, SqlConnection connection)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE ##" + tableName + " (ID int)", connection);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    DataTable localTempTable = new DataTable(tableName);

    DataColumn id = new DataColumn();
    id.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
    id.ColumnName = "ID";
    localTempTable.Columns.Add(id);

    System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw1 = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();        

    sw1.Start();
    foreach (var item in ids)
    {
        DataRow row = localTempTable.NewRow();
        row[0] = item;
        localTempTable.Rows.Add(row);

    }
    localTempTable.AcceptChanges();
    long temp1 = sw1.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    sw1.Reset();
    using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
    {
        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "##" + tableName;
        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(localTempTable);

    }
    long temp2 = sw1.ElapsedMilliseconds;
}
```

Result when AccpetChanges is inside foreach loop

[image]

And when it’s not

[image]

Difference is 3 orders of magnitude :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [IDataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader(v=vs.110).aspx) and it will run even faster

instead of `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`
Execute

```
cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

Comment: You are right that using a IDataReader is better than doing a DataTable but you are incorrect about doing `cmd.ExectuteReader()`, it still should be `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` because the code does not actually return any result sets.